# DataGridView ComboBox Columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, datatable

I have a datagridview that is populated by a dataset. I am attempting to add 3 columns that contains comboboxs with their own datasource which would also be a dataset.

Removing CRUD control here is how I am attempting to add the combobox columns.

```
Private Sub GenComboBoxColumns()
    Dim priorityTypesDS As New DataSet()
    Dim serviceBoardsDS As New DataSet()
    Dim serviceTypesDS As New DataSet()

    priorityTypesDS = _objhost.GetDataSet("SELECT DISTINCT abc FROM foo ORDER BY abc")
    serviceBoardsDS = _objhost.GetDataSet("SELECT DISTINCT abc FROM bar ORDER BY abc")
    serviceTypesDS = _objhost.GetDataSet("SELECT DISTINCT abc, xyz FROM foobar ORDER BY xyz")


    If dataGridView_monitorMapping IsNot Nothing AndAlso dataGridView_monitorMapping.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim col_priority As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        Dim col_serviceBoard As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        Dim col_serviceType As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

        col_priority.DataSource = priorityTypesDS
        col_serviceBoard.DataSource = serviceBoardsDS
        col_serviceType.DataSource = serviceTypesDS

        dataGridView_monitorMapping.Columns.AddRange(col_priority, col_serviceBoard, col_serviceType)

    End If
```

End Sub

However I am actually generating numerous columns which run off the view area contained within the datagridview (over 7 columns!) when their should only be 3.

To help you understand what I am trying to accomplish take a look at this example below. Think of a combobox and its respective options noted as such (foo*Bar*FooBar*) => a combobox with 3 choices.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Apple          | (plant*animal) |  (blue*green*red*etc)  |     (smooth*rough*) |
|Steak          | (plant*animal) |  (blue*green*red*etc)  |     (smooth*rough*) |
|Peach          | (plant*animal) |  (blue*green*red*etc)  |     (smooth*rough*) |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As always; help is most appreciated! =)

Comment: So the problem is that its adding many more columns to the grid than intended? Are the extra columns duplicates, or something else? Where are you calling `GenComboBoxColumns` from?

Comment: GenComboBox is being called in multiple locations; whenever the main datagridview is "synced" (cleared and repopulated with new data) this is required to recreate the columns to the now cleared table (whenever synced).   

Not only am I getting more columns than I need; they are not even populated with the datasets (which do contain the proper information within their internal tables).  

I bet it's a looping issue; however I would think the comboboxs would be populated with the correct data  at least.

Comment: I would give the columns names and check to make sure they don't already exist in the grid before adding them, just to make sure they are only loaded once. You could try setting the `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` properties of the  `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to see if that helps with the population. When you say not populated, do they have no values, or the wrong values?